# JOIN data from same table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table containing the names, emails, positions, etc of a students, as well as their "status" (which can be one of Y or N.) I want to write a query that counts the number of each type of position, as well as the number of Y AND the number of N within each type using JOIN. (That is, it would be a table with three columns: Position, StatusIsYes, and StatusIsNo.)

I have already done this using the CASE clause the following way, but I can't figure out how to do it using the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT position,
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS StatusIsYes,
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS StatusIsNo
 FROM 
students GROUP BY crd
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

EDIT: I know it can be done *without* using JOIN, but I want to know how it is possible to do it *with* a JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SELF JOIN in the case when you want to fetch records from same table.
For ex:
**Table Name**: employee
**Fields** : EmpId,EmpName,ManagerId
Now if you want to get the details of Empolyees who are in Manager Position for that we need to write query like this:
SELECT e1.EmpId, e1.EmpName FROM EmployeeDetails e1, EmployeeDetails e2 where e1.EmpId=e2.ManagerId;

Hope it will help you.

Fro more information please check [this](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-self-join.php) link.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a join:

```
SELECT
    position,
    SUM(status = 'Y') AS StatusIsYes,
    SUM(status = 'N') AS StatusIsNo
FROM students
GROUP BY position
```

Note the rather funky dispensing of the `CASE`, because in mysql (only) `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so `sum()` of a condition counts how many times it is true :)

Comment: Thanks - that does look much cleaner than what I had. However I'd like to figure out how to do it using JOIN; I'm told it's possible but I can't figure out how. But +1 anyway

Comment: Not only do you not *need* a join, it doesn't make any sense to use one either - doing so would just be for the sake of doing so, but would be a bad solution

Comment: you're right. I just wanted some more practise with JOIN clauses and the solution using a JOIN wasn't obvious to me here

Answer (score 1):

Try ::

```
SELECT 
position,
COUNT(status = 'Y' ) AS StatusIsYes,
COUNT(status = 'N' ) AS StatusIsNo
 FROM 
students GROUP BY POSITION
```

Comment: @Bohemian: You are superfast...:-)