# How to do self join on a table.

Tags: sql

I need to write a self join query

My Table is:-

```
id locid parentid filename 

1    1      0       word 
2    1      0       excel 
3    1      1       power 
4    2      0       word 
5    2      4       power
```

> I need to retrive only those data where parentid=0 using selfjoin

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why a self join ? If you want to retrieve data with parentid=0, why not just `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE parentId=0` ?

Comment: Retrieve data using what criteria ? You don't need self join to merely select records where `parentid = 0`

Comment: What result you want from above table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query its not clear based on which do u want to use self join.

Anyway below is one example which will give u clear picture about self join.

Suppose Employees is table which contains data related to employees. 
An Employee can be manager for other employee but single itself consider as employee for any organization.

Exmaple:

TableName : employees

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    ManagerID         
    1            A            null         
    2            B             1         
    3            C             1         
    4            D             3         
    5            E             3
```

Query:

```
select e1.EmployeeName as Employee,
    e2.EmployeeName as ReportsTo
from employees e1 
left outer join employees e2
on e1.ManagerID  = e2.EmployeeID 
order by e1.EmployeeID
```

OutPut will be as below:

```
Employee  Reports To
-------- ----------- 
  B          A    
  C          A    
  D          C    
  E          C
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need a self-join since you can get all you need with a `WHERE`-clause:

```
SELECT
    id, locid, parentid, filename
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
WHERE
    parentid = 0
```

Maybe you want also all columns of the parent record:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS ParentID, p.locid AS PlocID, p.parentid AS ParentID, p.filename AS ParentFileName,
    c.id, c.locid, c.parentid, c.filename
FROM
    dbo.YourTable p
    INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable c 
        ON p.id = c.parentid
WHERE
    c.parentid = 0
```

Comment: @user1947927: I'm glad to hear that. However, Himanshu seems to have the better query ;)

Comment: Probably just do a left join to include the records with no parents

Answer (score 2):

i used this :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(ID NUMBER, locid NUMBER, parentid NUMBER, filename VARCHAR2(10));
BEGIN

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,1,0,'word');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(2,1,0,'excel');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(3,1,1,'power');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(4,2,0,'word');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(5,2,4,'power');
END;
/
```

the usual way is :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;

select * from my_table  where parentid=0;

SELECT  distinct t1.ID, t1.locid, t1.parentid, t1.filename FROM my_table t1
JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.parentid = t2.parentid AND t2.parentid = 0;
```

it resuls as:

```
1   1   0   word
2   1   0   excel
4   2   0   word
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *.t1
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.parentid AND t2.parentid = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for self join. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279757/join-data-from-same-table), I have already given the explanation for it.

For ex:
**Table Name**: employee
**Fields** : EmpId,EmpName,ManagerId

Now if you want to get the details of Empolyees who are in Manager Position for that we need to write query like this:

```
SELECT e1.EmpId, e1.EmpName 
FROM EmployeeDetails e1, EmployeeDetails e2 
where e1.EmpId=e2.ManagerId;
```

Hope it will help you.

For more information please check [this](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-self-join.php) link.